# Can't find 'EDB Language Pack' option in Stack Builder of PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to install the EDB Language Pack to make PL/Python available with PostgreSQL 13.
But I can't find 'EDB Language Pack' option from Stack Builder of PostgreSQL 13.
Does anyone know how I can get the EDB Language Pack for PostgreSQL 13?

I found that the Stack Builder of PostgreSQL 13 does not have the EDB Language Pack option, but the Stack Builder of PostgreSQL 15 does.
On the left side of the picture is Stack Builder for PostgreSQL 13.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnzJN.jpg)